# Sed - replace a part of line - a word in quotes

Tags: regex, sed

what I have:

```
property = "value"
```

where value is a random string that I don't know the value of. What I want:

```
property = "new_value"
```

Following dooes not work for me:

```
"s|property = \"*\"|property = \"new_value\"|g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following replacement seems to work in Sed:

```
echo "property = \"value\"" | sed 's/"[^"]\+"/"new_value"/';
```

This outputs:

```
property = "new_value"
```

We match on the pattern `"[^"]\+"`, and then replace with `"new_value"`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.